# Finding all unique paths in tree structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

Let's say I have a directory structure laid out in a text file

```
root1
    child1
    child2
        grandchild1
        grandchild2
    child3
root2
    child1
    child2
        grandchild1
            greatgrandchild1
```

How can I turn the above tree structure into a nested array that looks like this:

```
[
    [ "root1", "child1" ],
    [ "root1", "child2", "grandchild1" ],
    [ "root1", "child2", "grandchild2" ],
    [ "root1", "child3" ],
    [ "root2", "child1" ],
    [ "root2", "child2", "grandchild1", "greatgrandchild1" ]
]
```

**edit**

Getting further but still having issues walking through the tree recursively

```
var $text = ''
+ 'root1\n'
+ '  r1 child1\n'
+ '  r1 child2\n'
+ '    r1 grandchild1\n'
+ '    r1 grandchild2\n'
+ '  r1 child3\n'
+ 'root2\n'
+ '  r2 child1\n'
+ '    r2 c1\n'
+ '      r2 c1 g1\n'
+ '  r2 child2\n'
+ '    r2 grandchild1\n'
+ '      r2 greatgrandchild1\n'
+ 'test!\n'
+ 'root3\n'
+ '  r3 child1\n'
+ '    r3 c1\n'
+ '      r3 c1 g1\n'
+ '  r3 child3\n'
+ '    r3 grandchild1\n'
+ '      r3 greatgrandchild1';

var dirGen = (function(trees) {
  "use strict";

  var indent = /[\s\t]/g;
  var lTrim = /[\s\t]*/;
  var $trees = decompose(trees);
  var $root = [];

  function init() {
    var paths = $trees.map(treeMap)
    $test(paths);
  }

  function treeMap(tree, n, arr) {
    var base = new LinkedList();
    return bfs(-1, tree, base);
  }

  function bfs(n, tree, base) {
    var l, t;
    n++;
    //base case
    if (n === tree.length) return trails(base);
    l = tree.length;
    t = tree[n];
    var cur = { label: t.replace(lTrim, ""), depth: depth(t), children: [] };
    //set root
    if (n === 0) {
      base.tree = cur;
      return bfs(n, tree, base);
    }

    base.push(cur);

    return bfs(n, tree, base);

  }

  function depth(str) {
    var d = str.match(indent);
    if (d === null) return 0;
    return d.length;
  }

  function trails(arr) {
    return arr;
  }

  function LinkedList() {}

  LinkedList.prototype.push = function(node) {   
    var l = this.tree.children.length;
    var j = l - 1;
    if (l === 0) {
      this.tree.children.push(node);
      return;
    }
    //walk through children array in reverse to get parent
    while (j > -1) {
      var d = this.tree.children[j].depth;
      //child
      if (node.depth > d) {
        console.log(this.tree.children[j], node)
        return this.tree.children[j].children.push(node);
      }
      //sibling
      if (node.depth === d) {

      }

      j--;
    }

  }

  function decompose(arr) {
    var treeBreak = /[\r\n](?=\w)/gm;
    var lines = /[\r\n]+(?!\s)*/g; 
    return arr.split(treeBreak).map(function(str) {
      return str.split(lines)
    });
  }

  function $test(str) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(str, null, 2);
    var wtf = "<pre>" + json + "</pre>";
    document.write(wtf);
  }

  return init;

})($text);

dirGen();
```

The code so far gets me this json array:

[image]

Comment: what is the new structure to be used for? Seems like it could be improved  to make it more friendly to recursive looping. Also what generates the text file? If its a script  you have access to you might kill 2 birds with one stone

Comment: @charlietfl the goal is to have an npm module that, when you initialize it, it will look for a directory template and automatically `mkdirp` the directory structure by joining the indices of each unique path array produced from the algorithm.

Comment: if you are doing that why are you writing to text file ? Doesn't make sense that you aren't writing to array at same time and make that nested array more of a traditional tree structure with same child node array names at each level

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough; the module uses `fs.readFileSync` to search for a text file that contains the directory structure you want to use. What I've coded so far converts the text file into data which needs to be used to `fs.mkdirp(target, callback)` for instance:

`var uniquePath = [ "root1", "child1", "grandchild1" ];
fs.mkdirp(uniquePath.join("/"), function(err, res) { //directory created });`

Comment: the two general algorithms to look for this problem would be **depth-first traversal** and **breadth-first traversal**

Comment: omg, I just realized that I did something a little different than you asked for x-)

Comment: However, based on my structure you can easily get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question)

Ok so the implementation actually has three parts: (1) converting the text file into a tree structure and then (2) using dfs on the tree to find the unique paths, and finally (3) merging all the paths into a single array.

First, the text to tree converter. You still need to find the depth (level of indentation) of each item because that's what determines if it is a child or sibling:

```
var treeGrapher = (function() {
  "use strict";

  var find = require("lodash.find");

  var indent = /[\s\t]/g;
  var lTrim = /[\s\t]*/;
  var treeBreak = /[\r\n](?=\w)/gm;
  var lines = /[^\r\n]+/g

  function init(text) {
    return decompose(text).map(function(tree) {
      return populate(-1, tree, {})
    });
  }

  function depth(str) {
    var d = str.match(indent);
    if (d === null) return 0;
    return d.length;
  }

  function decompose(txt) {
    return txt.split(treeBreak).map(function(str) {
      return str.match(lines);
    });
  }

  function populate(n, tree, root, cache, breadCrumbs) {
    var branch, leaf, crumb;
    //set index
    n++;
    //root case
    if (n === tree.length) return root.tree;

    branch = tree[n];
    leaf = { label: branch.replace(lTrim, ""), index: n, depth: depth(branch), children: [] };
    breadCrumbs = breadCrumbs || [];
    crumb = cache ? { label: cache.label, index: cache.index, depth: cache.depth, node: cache } : undefined;

    //set root
    if (n === 0) { 
      root.tree = leaf;
      return populate(n, tree, root, leaf, breadCrumbs);
    }

    //push child to cached parent from previous iteration
    if (leaf.depth > cache.depth) {
      cache.children.push(leaf);
      root.parent = cache;
      breadCrumbs.push(crumb)
      return populate(n, tree, root, leaf, breadCrumbs);
    }

    //push child to distant parent via breadcrumb search
    if (leaf.depth <= cache.depth) {
      var rev = breadCrumbs.slice(0).reverse();
      var parentNode = find(rev, function(obj){ return obj.depth < leaf.depth }).node;
      parentNode.children.push(leaf);
      return populate(n, tree, root, leaf, breadCrumbs);
    }

  }

  return init;

})();

module.exports = treeGrapher;
```

Then, the dfs. This algorithm only searches one tree at a time so if your directory structure has multiple roots you need to put it in a loop.

```
var uniquePaths = (function() {
  "use strict";

  function init(tree) {
    return walk(tree, [], []);
  }

  function walk(branch, path, basket) {
    var fork = path.slice(0);
    var i = 0;
    var chld = branch.children;
    var len = chld.length;
    fork.push(branch.label);
    if (len === 0) { 
      basket.push(fork);
      return basket;
    }
    for (i; i < len; i++) walk(chld[i], fork, basket);
    return basket;
  }

  return init;

})();

module.exports = uniquePaths;
```

Putting them together would look like this:

**directory.tmpl.txt**

```
root1
    child1
    child2
        gc1
root2
root3
    root3-child1
```

**main.js**

```
var fs = require("fs");
var treeGrapher = require("./lib/treeGrapher.js");
var uniquePaths = require("./lib/uniquePaths.js");  

var tmpl = fs.readFileSync("./director.tmpl.txt", "utf8");
var graphs = treeGrapher(tmpl); //returns an array of trees
var paths = arrange(graphs);

/**    
[ 
    [ "root1", "rootchild1" ],
    [ "root1", "child2", "gc1" ],
    [ "root2" ],
    [ "root3", "root3-child1" ]
]
*/

function arrange(trees) {
    var bucket = [];
    trees.forEach(function(list) {
        uniquePaths(list).forEach(function(arr) {
            bucket.push(arr);
        });
    });
    return bucket;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm too lazy to read your algorithm :-|

```
function populateTree (tree, text) {
    var rTab, rChunks, rChunk;
    var chunks, chunk;
    var i, l, node;
    if (!text) return;
    rTab    = /^\s{4}/gm;
    rChunks = /[\r\n]+(?!\s{4})/g;
    rChunk  = /^(.+)(?:[\r\n]+((?:\r|\n|.)+))?$/;
    chunks  = text.split(rChunks);
    l       = chunks.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        chunk = chunks[i].match(rChunk);
        node = { label: chunk[1], children: [] };
        tree.children.push(node);
        populateTree(node, chunk[2] && chunk[2].replace(rTab, ''));
    }
}

function printTree(tree, prefix) {
    var i, l = tree.children.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(prefix + tree.children[i].label);
        printTree(tree.children[i], prefix + '  ');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var tree = { children: [] };
populateTree(tree, text);
printTree(tree, '');
```

I'm not familiar with Nodejs, I can only tell that it works in Chrome with this string:

```
var text = ''
+ 'root1\n'
+ '    child1\n'
+ '    child2\n'
+ '        grandchild1\n'
+ '        grandchild2\n'
+ '    child3\n'
+ 'root2\n'
+ '    child1\n'
+ '    child2\n'
+ '        grandchild1\n'
+ '            greatgrandchild1';
```

Comment: Thanks for the start, this is really useful :)